# Centering main next to a sidebar

Tags: html, css, center, program-entry-point, sidebar

I apologize in advance if this has been asked before but unfortunately I can't seem to find an answer - maybe I used the wrong terms while searching.

However. I am building a very simple website to display my portfolio and I decided to put a fixed sidebar on the left and the main contents scrolling on the right. Let's say the "active part" of the website begins where the sidebar ends, and I need my contents centered between the end of the sidebar and the end of the browser window.

I float the contents to the right and manage to make it look like I want it to but only by setting specific margins.

> [image: screenshot]

As you can see the result viewed on my laptop, which is correct on this resolution, but if the size of the window increases, the contents remain, obviously, on the right, and the left margin becomes bigger than the right margin which I don't want.

Is it possible to make the main setting itself at the center so that the two margins are even on different resolutions?

HTML

```
<div id="main">

<div class="title-contents">
    <h1 class="page-name">Stuff I Make</h1>
    <div class="gallery-icon"><a href="grid.html"><img src="images/grid-icon.jpg"/></a></div>
    <div class="gallery-icon"><a href="banners.html"><img src="images/line-icon.jpg"/></a></div>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#main {
background-color:#fff;
width:780px;
height:100%;
margin:60px;
float:right;
padding-left:40px;
padding-right:40px;
padding-top:40px;
padding-bottom:60px;
}
```

Thanks to everyone of you who will read and eventually answer and please forgive my clear lack of knowledge, I started doing this a couple of weeks ago so if this question is beyond stupid just try to understand, ahah ;) Thank you!

Veronica

EDIT: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LmqvbtLk/)...I hope it's clear. As you can see the main sticks to the right because I set it to float:right, but if I set it to float:center it stays in the middle of the page goind UNDER the sidebar. I want it to always stay centered WITHIN the space next to the sidebar.

To answer the question, the sidebar has a fixed width. Thanks!!!! :)

Comment: can you please post a fiddle too..

Comment: The answer is probably not very complicated, you just have to clarify what exactly do you want as I didn't understand

Comment: This depends a lot on the entire setup. Does the sidebar has a fixed or percentage width..?

Comment: There is no "float:center;"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using a percentage layout, I suggest you to use TJ's answer.

If you want the sidebar to have a fixed width, I made you this solution, using absolute position on the main part:

HTML:

```
<div id="sidebar">
    sidebar
</div>

<div id="main">
    <div>
        content
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 150px;
    height: 100%;
    background: lightblue;
}
#main {
    position: absolute;
    top: 25px;
    right: 25px;
    bottom: 25px;
    left: 175px; /* width of #sidebar + extra margin */
}
#main > div {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    background: lightgreen;
}
```

What it does: the sidebar has a fixed place and a fix width. If you want you can add margin to it by playing around with the top, left and bottom position.

The `#main` div is placed absolute. The top, right and bottom position are all set to the same number (in the example 25px). The left position is the width of the sidebar plus the extra margin (in the example 150 + 25 = 175px;

Also see [**this demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/8Lzq9q4p/).

Footnote: the extra div inside `#main` is for when the length of the content is bigger than `#main`, and the background will expand. See this [extra demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8Lzq9q4p/1/). In case it all fits inside it, just remove the div (and put a background on `#main`).

Comment: Thank you so much! This seems to work, I tried all the solutions and this is the best for my case since the sidebar has a fixed width. Only problem is, when removing the float:right from the #main the white background doesn't fit the height of the contents. I tried to force clear:both and to implement the #main > div as you suggested but the only thing that seems to stretch the background properly is the float:right and I can't understand why since I don't know how they could be related. Any guess?

Comment: I don't use float in my code? Can you be more clear what doesn't work with my code?

Comment: What I mean is, the extra code you wrote for when the lenght of the content is bigger than #main doesn't work and I can't figure out why. The background "ends" before the contents and the only thing that make it the lenght I want is putting float:right back on the #main css. I will try to post fiddle when I am home again, I was just wondering if it's a common problem or what. As I said I tried clear:both and other stuff but so far no luck. :(

Comment: Therefor I have the extra div (for the longer content). But please post the Fiddle so I can see what you mean.

Comment: Hello again! I've been busy working, I'm sorry, anyway I managed to fix the problem by adding a clear div under my gallery, since the background didn't see my floating elements. I know it's not the most elegant solution but it works for me. So thank you for your answer, you've been very helpful :):):) x

Comment: Your welcome. Glad you found the solution. If this answer suits you, please don't forget to mark it as solution (v-mark on the left of it).

Answer (score 1):

You need a container for the sidebar and content. You can fixed position the sidebar and center align the content in the remaining space by applying `padding-left` equal to the width of sidebar and  `margin:0 auto` for the container.

Following is a quick responsive setup:

HTML

```
<div id="page">
  <div id="sidebar"></div>
  <div id="main"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#page{
  height:100%;
  padding-left:10%; // equal to the width of sidebar
}
#sidebar{
    position:fixed;
    top:10%;
    left:0;
    width:10%;
    height:80%;
}
#main {
    width: 80%;
    height: 100%;
    margin:0 auto; // center align horizontally
}
```

Try resizing the output window in following fiddle:

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/7emu8t7L/)

Answer (score -1):

Not sure what you are looking for but maybe this?

**HTML**

```
<div class="one">

    Here's room for the side menu

    <ul>
        <li>option 1</li>
        <li>option 2</li>
        <li>option 3</li>
        <li>option 4</li>
        <li>option 5</li>
        <li>option 6</li>
        <li>option 7</li>
        <li>option 8</li>
        <li>option 9</li>
    </ul>

</div>

<div class="two">

        <div id="main">

        <div class="title-contents">
            <h1 class="page-name">Stuff I Make</h1>

            <div style="clear:both"></div>
        </div>

    </div>

  </div>
```

**CSS**

```
#main {
border: 2px solid red;
width:80%;
height:100%;
margin: 0 auto;
padding-left:40px;
padding-right:40px;
padding-top:40px;
padding-bottom:60px;
box-sizing: border-box;  
}

.one {
    border: 2px solid green;
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    display: block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 100%;
}

.two {
    border: 2px solid blue;
    float: left;
    width: 80%;
    display: block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zz44wcrc/)

Comment: @LinkinTED, what fixed sidebar?

Comment: please read the OP again "*...and I decided to put a __fixed sidebar__ on the left and ...*"

Comment: @LinkinTED, as I mentioned in my answer, I wasn't exactly sure of what the asker wanted. Furthermore, the fiddle that contained the sidebar was added **after** I posted my answer: the original problem the user posted was centering the "Stuff I make" part - which you can see by the original code posted by the asker - in the area to the right. Despite being what the user asked for or not, I was just trying to help and the user should know if it suited his needs or not. I don't think your downvote and finger pointed at me helped the user in any way. It may have made you happy though.

Comment: Why are downvotes always taken so personally? The original OP already had the text "fixed sidebar", imo, there is only one way you can interpret that. Sure you provide an answer and reach out a hand, but you didn't take the time to read carefully. If the question isn't clear, leave a comment and ask for elaboration.

Comment: @LinkinTED, downvotes aren't taken personally by me, I just found yours to be unnecessary. If you see an incorrect or partially correct answer (in this case, mine) I think you should comment so the user can improve his answer and/or write a better answer yourself (which you did). Is the downvote really necessary? If the answer is completely off, then yes, a downvote. It's not a question of having `-2` reputation that bothers me, it's just the downvote trigger happy attitude. By the way, your answer is very good

Comment: I downvote if the answer doesn't give the (full) answer that the OP wishes. Especially when certain requirements are written in the OP, but aren't used. If the answer gets updated I'll undownvote.

Comment: @LinkinTED, I'm sorry, I didn't know you followed that rule for downvoting. Since I usually follow [another rule](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down), that says `Downvotes should be used whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect`, I thought everyone here followed it: my mistake.

Comment: Then we should discuss whether your answer is sloppy or not ;)